# Java for loop iterate and list colors

Tags: java, for-loop, colors

In this code

```
int[] values = new int[] {0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192, 224, 255};
        for (int r = 0; r < values.length; r++){
          for (int g = 0; g < values.length; g++){
            for (int b = 0; b < values.length; b++) {
                System.out.println("Colors are: " + values[r]+ ","+values[g]+ ","+values[b]);
```

I have a list of colors but they are not ordered: I wish to change this for loop so to get a list of ordered colors starting from white down to black, or the opposite, black to white.

How change this loop?

Thank you very much

Comment: It is already the case: white = (0,0,0) is first and black = (255,255,255) is last. You need to be more specific as to what order you want.

Comment: What do you mean by the term "ordered colors"? Order like in rainbow?

Comment: Yes I mean starting from the brigther one (white) and increase dark down to black, so in example, white, yellow, orange, red, brown black.

Comment: What about colours with the same brightness? Do you want them in any particular order?

Comment: @ Peter Lawrey: no need for particular order, I just need a comprehensive list of ordered colors starting from white down to black.

Comment: e.g. there are 46 colours with a brightness of 128.

Comment: What I want to avoid is to get, in example, black, blue,green, brown then again green, orange, blue, red, green again and so on. I wish to have a ordered list of colors starting from white then slightly increase to yellow, then slightly increase again to orange and so on down to black.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would write it this way

```
int[] values = new int[]{0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192, 224, 255};
SortedMap<Long, Color> colours = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
for (int r : values) {
    for (int g : values) {
        for (int b : values) {
            long brightness = (r + g + b) / 3;
            long colourScore = (brightness << 24) + (r << 8) + (g << 16) + b;
            colours.put(colourScore, new Color(r,g,b));
        }
    }
}
for (Color color : colours.values()) {
    System.out.println(color);
}
```

This favours red and green over blue as blue tinting is associated with night. ;)  It prints

```
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=224]
java.awt.Color[r=224,g=255,b=255]
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=224,b=255]
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=192]
java.awt.Color[r=224,g=255,b=224]
java.awt.Color[r=192,g=255,b=255]
... many deleted ...
java.awt.Color[r=32,g=0,b=32]
java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=64]
java.awt.Color[r=0,g=32,b=0]
java.awt.Color[r=32,g=0,b=0]
java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=32]
java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=0]
```

Comment: +1 But maybe give G the highest significance, since it is in the middle of the spectrum, and the eye has the greatest sensitivity to it?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need:

1. a `Color` class that represents a full RGB triplet;
2. implement `Comparable` on `Color`, whereby deciding exactly what constitutes your desired color order;
3. in your nested loop you'll build a `TreeSet` of all colors. When you iterate over it, you'll get the colors in your desired order.

Since colors are inherently three-dimensional entities, it is not quite obvious how to linearize their order, so you'll have to make some compromises.